# Replace some values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sage

Im trying to replace some values in a Numpy array using sagemath. 
I want to conserve the unchanged array too.

```
sage: N=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[8,9,7]])
```

I call K the new array (with some values replaced):

```
sage: K=N sage: K array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [8, 9, 7]])

sage: K[1,2]=9

sage: K array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 9], [8, 9, 7]])
```

But here is the problem: the original array is changed too!!

```
sage: N array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 9], [8, 9, 7]])
```

How can I do for change only the array `K` (and conserved without change the original array N)?

Answer (score 3):

You can make `K` a copy of `N`:

```
K = N.copy()
```

The issue that you're having is that in your original formulation, `K` is just a view of the same piece of memory that `N` points to.

Comment: @unutbu You're right. I was thinking `K[:] = A` if `K` already existed and was the same shape. I just removed it since it isn't the regular use case. Thanks for catching that typo.